# No module named 'zope.deprecation' with simple hello world pyramid app

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyramid

I am trying to learn how to deploy a pyramid app to AWS (Elastic Beanstalk), and I am taking it step by step, but I am stuck. I am using the [hello world app](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/firstapp.html) in order to keep it simple, but I am getting the following error and I don't know why:

```
[Mon Feb 20 18:08:33.477650 2017] [:error] [] mod_wsgi (pid=2811): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Feb 20 18:08:33.477918 2017] [:error] [] mod_wsgi (pid=2811): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Mon Feb 20 18:08:33.478124 2017] [:error] [] [remote 69.127.251.49:45648] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Feb 20 18:08:33.478329 2017] [:error] []   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Mon Feb 20 18:08:33.478440 2017] [:error] []     from pyramid.config import Configurator
[Mon Feb 20 18:08:33.478630 2017] [:error] []   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
[Mon Feb 20 18:08:33.478745 2017] [:error] []     from pyramid.interfaces import (
[Mon Feb 20 18:08:33.478923 2017] [:error] []   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyramid/interfaces.py", line 1, in <module>
[Mon Feb 20 18:08:33.479050 2017] [:error] []     from zope.deprecation import deprecated
[Mon Feb 20 18:08:33.479213 2017] [:error] [] ImportError: No module named 'zope.deprecation'
```

Code that I am trying to deploy is below. I uploaded this via the console.

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response


def hello_world(request):
    return Response('Hello %(name)s!' % request.matchdict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('hello', '/hello/{name}')
    config.add_view(hello_world, route_name='hello')
    application = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('', 8000, application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Steps I have taken:

SSH'ed into the instance and installed pyramid via

> sudo /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install pyramid

Checked pip freeze and it is present and in the correct venv

```
(venv)[ec2-user@ ~]$ pip list
hupper (0.4.2)
PasteDeploy (1.5.2)
pip (7.1.2)
pyramid (1.8.2)
repoze.lru (0.6)
setuptools (18.4)
translationstring (1.3)
venusian (1.0)
WebOb (1.7.1)
zope.deprecation (4.2.0)
zope.interface (4.3.3)

(venv)[ec2-user@ ~]$ pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages(python 3.4)
```

I've tried to invoke the module from python directly without success

```
(venv)[ec2-user@ ~]$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Sep  1 2016, 23:33:38) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from zope.deprecation import deprecation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'zope.deprecation'
>>>
```

Interestingly, `help('modules')` doesn't show it, but it does show pyramid.
I've also tried to install it directly. The module is in /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages.

I am out of ideas, and I am tempted to ditch this approach and try the EB CLI.

This sounds like I am missing something really obvious. Also, since this is a simple one file script I don't have a setup.py to run.

Other things I have tried:

- Blow away the entire app and try again.
- Tried Pyramid 1.7 and zope.deprecation 4.1.2 on a new app.
- Tried using a requirements.txt file.

One of the last steps have made python able to recognize zope.deprecation. App still doesn't work as it is back to

> Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.

Not sure if this is progress or not.

### UPDATE

GOT IT WORKING. I think the secret was rolling back versions, adding a requirements.txt, and changing the location of the application variable in application.py.

application.py now looks like

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response


def hello_world(request):
    return Response('Hello %(name)s!' % request.matchdict)

config = Configurator()
config.add_route('hello', '/hello/{name}')
config.add_view(hello_world, route_name='hello')
application = config.make_wsgi_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    server = make_server('', 8000, application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

I will experiment and hopefully add a better answer.

Comment: Pyramid 1.8.2 was release a day ago could be a bug. Have you tried with an older stable version of Pyramid?.

Comment: Rolled back to 1.7 and also rolled zope.deprecation to 4.1.2 and no good. I also tried putting them in a requirements.txt file and roll out a new app.

Comment: @webjunkie you were right...sort of. It turns out the version of zope.deprecation was the cause. It was installing 4.2 with pyramid 1.8.1 and bombing. I installed 4.1.2 and 1.8.1 worked. I still need to find out why.

Answer (score 2):

Errors like these occur frequently when mixing `setup.py <foo>` with `pip install <bar>` due to how each system handles namespace packages (like `zope.XXX`). The solution is usually to blow everything away and then install it using only one tool. For example if you're using `python setup.py develop` right now, replace it with `pip install -e .`

Comment: I'm using a single file python script so there isn't a setup.py. I am tempted to try that approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a reason yet, but the quick answer is that I needed to use zope.deprecation 4.1.2. Version 4.2 was causing things to break.

Comment: If that's the case then I'm even more sure about what I answered because it's clearly an installation issue of some sort.

Comment: Yes, definitely an install issue, but I've tried the install with both a requirements.txt and manually installing zope.deprecation 4.1.2 and pyramid 1.8.1 (in that order), and it works. Unfortunately, debugging 4.2 isn't a critical issue for me, so finding out what happened is low on my to do list.